# HDF5 Many Writers, One External Reader

Tags: algorithms

I have an application where I want to have 3 different machines writing to their own independent HDF5 files at a high rate, but have a way to read data from them externally and combine it. Is HDF5 a good way to do that or should I look into another format?

My main purpose is I have 3 independent packet capturing boxes that will be capturing at about 10Gbps each. They all filtered for specific UDP messages and drop all the rest of the traffic. Inside of these UDP messages there are 3 different types of data, which can be thought of as C structs. These UDP messages need to be written to disk (and possibly formatted differently) in a time series format so that I can search them later. My ultimate goal is to be able to load them into MATLAB quickly, which likely means HDF5 since that's the native format there. I was looking in to PyTables and TsTables, but I'm not quite sure if these do what I want. PyTables doesn't look like it's for time series, and TsTables looks fairly immature.

Comment: Maybe? What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just edited my original question to be more detailed. Thanks.

Comment: You might want a Time Series Database rather than a file. Something like [InfluxDB](http://influxdb.com/), maybe.

Comment: Do you know how that compares to something like TsTables with PyTables? Importing into MATLAB is a crucial step. It looks like InFluxDB has a capability of running queries, so I'll have to see how MATLAB can interact with that.

Comment: You can't really do anything with "files" at 10GB/s, what is the data-rate after filtering?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. The network traffic is about 10Gbps, but it's filtered before writing to about 8MB/s